# interpretation of "nor...not"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

"We feel discomfort in their absence, but not because their absence results directly in physical discomfort; nor would a taste not trained to discriminate between the conventionally good and the conventionally bad take offence at their omission."

I'm kind of confusing in reading this sentence since there is 'not' in the nor clause.
Is it safe to change the underlined sentence as 'a taste trained to discriminate between the conventionally good and the conventionally bad would take offence at their omission.'?

Comment: If you change **a taste not trained** to **a taste trained**, you make the clause mean the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

"nor would a taste not trained to discriminate between the conventionally good and the conventionally bad take offence at their omission".

The above can be "translated" as: "and also (in addition), a taste not trained to discriminate between the conventionally good and the conventionally bad **would not  take offence** at their omission".

Hopefully, it resolves your confusion.